# Why does my Preview Window doesn't show FormElement Content

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to add a [sap.ui.layout.form.Form](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.form.Form.html) with [FormContainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.form.FormContainer.html) and [FormElements](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement.html) to a Preview [Dialog](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.Dialog.html). However, my Form and its Elements doesn't get rendered.
[Click Here](http://jsbin.com/gurutowamo/edit?html,output):

```
{
  "Type": "sap.ui.core.mvc.JSONView",
  "content": [
    {
      "Type": "sap.m.Button",
      "id": "testitemid0",
      "text": "MyTestButton",
      "press": "asdf"
    },
    {
      "Type": "sap.ui.layout.form.Form",
      "id": "testitemid1",
      "formContainers": [
        {
          "Type": "sap.ui.layout.form.FormContainer",
          "id": "testitemid2",
          "formElements": [
            {
              "Type": "sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement",
              "id": "testitemid3",
              "label": {
                "Type": "sap.m.Label",
                "id": "testitemid4",
                "text": "My Test Label"
              },
              "fields": [
                {
                  "Type": "sap.m.Input",
                  "id": "testitemid5",
                  "value": "My Test Input",
                  "placeholder": ""
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Any Idea why it doesn't render the Form?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sap.ui.layout.form.Form-Element simply lacks a layout:

```
{
  "Type": "sap.ui.layout.form.Form",
  "id": "testitemid1",
  "layout": {
      "Type": "sap.ui.layout.form.GridLayout"
  },
  ...
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vajuxunamu/edit?html,output)